# Why doesn't nth-of-type work?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<section class="history">
  <div class="asked">
    <h1 class="user-show-tab-title">Questions</h1>
    <div>
      <ul class="question-index-false"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="answered">
    <h1 class="user-show-tab-title">Answers</h1>
    <div>
      <ul class="question-index-false"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I'm desperately trying to select and style the 2nd `h1` element with the class "user-show-tab-title" (the one with "answers")
but for some reason `.user-show-tab-title:nth-of-type(1)` selects them both and `.user-show-tab-title:nth-of-type(2)` doesn't select anything.

What gives?

Comment: Because they are under different parents and each parent has only one `h1`.

Comment: At great risk of stating the obvious: You do know that in this scenario you can just target the element using the parent, right... ie. `.answered h1 {...}`

Comment: @Mikk3lRo Yes, I just realized the OP thought that `nth-of-type(1)` would select the second one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because they are both the first of type `h1` within a div. `nth-of-type` applies only to immediate child relationship.

Also note that the `nth` related selectors start at 1, so to select the second you would use 2, not 1.

I don't know your actual HTML, but for what you have, you can just use

```
.answered .user-show-tab-title
```

If you really want to use `nth-of-type`, here's how you can use it. I'm inserting some dummy `<p>`s otherwise, all the children of `<section>` would be of the same type.

```css
.history div:nth-of-type(1) .user-show-tab-title {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.history div:nth-of-type(2) .user-show-tab-title {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
    <section class="history">
      <p>Dummy paragraph</p>
      <p>Dummy paragraph</p>
      <div class="asked">
        <h1 class="user-show-tab-title">Questions</h1>
        <div>
          <ul class="question-index-false"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Dummy paragraph</p>
      <p>Dummy paragraph</p>
      <p>Dummy paragraph</p>
      <div class="answered">
        <h1 class="user-show-tab-title">Answers</h1>
        <div>
          <ul class="question-index-false"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can improve your answer by including `.history div:nth-of-type(2) .user-show-tab-title` which would show the correct usage.

Comment: @Mikk3lRo I guess I can also show an example of a usage that works and makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just select `.answered h1` instead? :) your selector won't work because they are under different parents.